# Azure performance testing: Link VSTS account

Tags: azure, load-testing

I need to load test a website on Azure. I created my load test and then it tells me I need a Team Services account to run my test. So I click on create account and it asks me about a Name, a Subscription and a location.

Will the subscription I link to this account be usable for other future accounts?

I'm not the owner of the website and I don't want to create a Team Services account if it prevents the owner to create another one later.